# "videoMediaMetadata" not working, but "imageMediaMetadata" is okay

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

[Update] Figured out the problem. See my answer in comment. Incognito mode could possibly be causing the problem too.

I desperately need help as this is supposed to be going Live really soon. The script used to work for both JPEG and MP4. After I committed a go live date, suddenly the script doesn't like MP4 file and just rejects it entirely. It knows........

Anyway, why is it that jpeg condition works fine, but not mp4?
Below the script, I've added the comment where it fails too:

```js
var file = "";
var getFile = "";
var width = "";
var height = "";

var findFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nameFile);
// actual script captures a file using its unique_file_name. It can be either jpeg or mp4

while (findFile.hasNext()) {
  file = findFile.next();
}
Logger.log(file.getName());
//put a logger here to ensure that file iterator is capturing the file

if (file.getMimeType().includes("jpeg")) {
  getFile = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).imageMediaMetadata
  width = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).imageMediaMetadata.width
  height = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).imageMediaMetadata.height

  Logger.log("Image meta data:" + getFile);

//if the file is a jpeg file, the scripts completes this with all information accurately captured.

} else if (file.getMimeType().includes("mp4")) {

  getFile = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).videoMediaMetadata
  Logger.log("Video meta data:" + getFile);
//The script fails here. getFile is returned as undefined

  width = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).videoMediaMetadata.width
  height = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).videoMediaMetadata.height
  duration = Drive.Files.get(file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true }).videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis

Logger.log("Video meta data:" + getFile);

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is Logger.log(file.getMimeType()); I'm thinking it might be `application/vnd.google-apps.video`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's not a script problem:

[image]

The reason why this is happening is because the Google Drive is still "processing the video" - and therefore no metadata available.